# Improving the error page with relevant, current information

Tags: discussion, feature-request, error-message, stack-status

When Stack Overflow is down/offline, we usually see the "Stack Overflow is currently offline" page with a bunch of error code images and links to [stackstatus.net](https://www.stackstatus.net/) and SO's Twitter page at https://twitter.com/StackStatus. Why not improve this page by embedding the relevant content of stackstatus.net and/or Twitter (directly or in an iframe) to display the status immediately, so that we don't have to follow a link to other sites? The images of code are cute and all, but they don't provide the useful information we need, which is located either on stackstatus.net or Twitter.

Comment: This page is designed to be a static page that can be very quickly loaded, sometimes by the CDN without even touching our servers. It's generally not possible to include dynamic content on it. If our servers are down and can't process the request at the moment, then it equally cannot process pulling in status information from somewhere else and displaying that.

Comment: @animuson "It's generally not possible to include dynamic content on it." Iframe?

Comment: I'd rather not see an error page with a loading indicator that I have to wait for in order to get information about the error. I very often don't even care about the extra information - a simple *fast loading* error page is enough. It means I can continue with my life and not sit and wait even more.

Comment: Not much reason to do anything more than link to stackstatus for those that wish to know more.

Comment: It [was down today](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/380959/sites-unavailable-intermittent-behaviour).

Comment: Just a couple of things, we host status elsewhere (and on a completely different domain with its own nameservers) both to be able to show status even when all of our infrastructure is down, and to offload some of that load - if the problem is load on the web servers, I don't think it's a great idea to have the web servers working hard to pull in extra information from some other place to display to you. If the site's down, enhancing the error page to give you more context doesn't really help anyone except it saved you a click.

Answer (score 9):

I tend to disagree with this sentiment. When I've attempted to access and hit the offline page, I agree with @VLAZ in that I often don't care about the extra information. If I am really concerned about it, taking the extra second to click the links to the other pages isn't too much work for me if I actually care about it. What is valuable and I think that SO does well in this case is it stops my search quickly with a relevant error page that gives enough detail so that I can quickly redirect my search elsewhere or atleast wait a while and retry in the near future.  Loading the error content that may or may not be relevant to that current outage seems like a cost that vastly outweighs the possibility of providing (maybe?) relevant information that would save me a link-click and 2 seconds.

Comment: This. Knowing that it's down is the only thing you need to know, the rest is merely curiosity.